# How to inherit _init_ from an instance of a class?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I would like to inherit all the `__init__` of an instance of a class. For example if a have a class Lens and a lens "L50mm" instance of it. I would like that my camera with the "L50mm" inherit all the `__init__` of the lens like this:

```
class Lens:
   def __init__(self,focallength,aperture):
       self.focallength=focallength
       self.aperture=aperture

L50mm=Lens(50,2.2)

class Camera:
    def __init__(self,name,sensor,lens='None'):
        self.name=name
        self.sensor=sensor
        if lens!='None':#if I have a lens mounted I want that all the __init__ is inherited e.g.:
            super(Lens).__init__()#something like this I KNOW it doesn't work
        else:#if I don't have a lens just keep 'None'
            self.lens=lens

mycamera=Camera('DSCF828','CCD',L50mm)
>>TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Of course I know that I can put `self.lens=lens` in the Camera `__init__` method but I was wondering if there is a more direct way to inherit all the properties.

The main goal is to access directly all the methods:

```
mycamera.focallength
mycamera.aperture
```

instead of:

```
mycamera.lens.aperture
mycamera.lens.focallength
```

Instead `self.lens = Lens()` as suggested in the comment doesn't make any sense for me beacause I would have to pass all the parameters again, so please read carefully the question.

Comment: You're not using using `super` the right way. `super` is used to call a method of a superclass. Maybe here you just want to create a new instance of a lens if it is `None` ? In that case you just want to replace the `super(Lens).__init__()` by `self.lens = Lens()`

Comment: What you're doing is is that a camera not only has a lens, but camera also **is-a lens**, now that does not make any sense.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala when I consider my object as a whole ofcourse this is only an exaple....

Comment: @loutre I have alreday written that at the end of my question I don't want to access the properties with Camera.Lens.property for this reason I have written this question...

Comment: @loutre I can't do that beacuse I would have to put all the paramter again....

Comment: 1. Your `Camera` needs to inherit from `Lens` 2. You must call `super()` the right way 3. You must pass the right parameters `focallength` and `aperture` to the initializer -- But honestly if I were you I'd go with composition over inheritance

Comment: To access the lens properties from `mycamera.focallength` etc, you can define a `Camera.__getattr__()` method, that catches missing attributes and passes them on to the object referenced in Camera.lens https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__

Comment: By the way, if you are on Python 2 remember to explicitly inherit from `object` (or, better, switch to Python 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if you really want to do inheritance actually, at least not in the traditional object oriented sense. Simply because the camera is not a lens, so theres no proper super/sub type relation between them.

What you might want is to wrap the attributes of `lens` in the `Camera`. I'm not saying it's a good idea, but it is sure possible. What you can do is to override the `__getattr__`:

```
 class Camera(object):
      def __getattr__(self, key):
            return getattr(self.lens, key)

      def __init__(self,name,sensor,lens=None):
             self.name=name
             self.sensor = sensor
             self.lens = lens
```

this means that if you have a camera object `cam` and tries to access a member of it, if that fails in the normal way it tries to use `getattr(self.lens, key)` instead. For example `cam.focallength` fails in the traditional sense (since there's no `focallength` in camera, but instead it will go on an try to effectively translate that into `cam.lens.focallength` instead.

Comment: Will this work? Shouldn't you use a try-except block and only try getattr on lens when the initial one raises an AttribueError?

Comment: @HåkenLid I hope so - the `__getattr__` method does not get called unless an attribute lookup in the usual places failed.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using composition instead of inheritance. 
This assumes that you know which properties you need from Lens.

```
class Camera:
    def __init__(self,name,sensor,lens=None):
        self.name=name
        self.sensor=sensor
        if lens is not None:
            self.focallength = lens.focallength
            self.aperture = lens.aperture
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you're not using POO the right way. If you *really* want to do that, try something like:

```
for attr in dir(lens):
    setattr(self, attr, getattr(attr, lens))
```

e.g:

```
class Lens:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, lens):
         for attr in dir(lens):
             setattr(self, attr, getattr(attr, lens))

lens = Lens(12, 13)
cam = Camera(lens)
cam.a
```

Read the answer's comments, you'll understand how dirty it is :)

Comment: Warning: `dir()` returns many special names, including `__class__`!

Comment: You should probably do something to avoid changing the attributes on `Camera` that already have a value.